# After email change I lost my all messages, favorites, etc

Tags: support, bug, login, accounts, merge-accounts

Yesterday I tried to change my email address of the account. Once I clicked on the verification link, sent to my email, I got an error that something went wrong. I had to login again. I did. But, then I noticed that all my messages, favorites, etc. were gone. Also my developer's story got messed up. I think I had an older account with the email I changed to. It seems that those two accounts got merged together somehow. I think I was a member for 1 year, 1 month. Now I'm a member for 1 year, 8 months. 
Is it possible to restore my account to the moment right before the email change? I really need an access to my messages history.

Comment: Umm... how do you think your dev story was messed up?

Comment: I filled a support form yesterday. I haven't gotten any response yet. How long it usually takes for them to look at requests? I was in contact with few people and now I think they won't be able to send me messages anymore.

Comment: Well, the Developer's story had a red sign. The name was changed, links to my twitter, github, and website were gone. I think the description was different too. Maybe something changed too, I just haven't noticed yet.

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/6314447 isn't what you expect it to be?

Comment: This is how it looks like after I have manually fixed it. Now it's probably fine. But after an email change it was distorted. The most important thing for me is to get my messages history back, so I could be in touch with some users again.

Comment: Okay... well you did the right thing by using the support form - you'd normally want to allow a couple of days for someone to get around to your ticket though (I'm not sure how the staff handle that - but if I see one later on that team I might see if I can't give 'em a ping to track it down and see if they can't get to it faster given it's about job stuff - but no guarantees there).